# Return Multimap ArrayList as String

Tags: java, guava, multimap

```
public static String getMRIScanSite(String val) {
    Multimap<String, String> map = HashMultimap.create();
    map.put("01", "131");
    map.put("04", "157");
    map.put("01", "158");
    map.put("109", "169");
    map.put("112", "170");

    Multimap<String, String> invertedMap = Multimaps.invertFrom(map, ArrayListMultimap.<String, String>create());
    return String.valueOf(invertedMap.get(val));
}
```

Is there any method to return multimap ArrayList to String ? I tried to convert to String using String.valueOf(), But result still in array. Thank you

current output :

```
"mriScansSite": "[01]"
```

expected output:

```
 "mriScansSite": "01"
```

Comment: What's the expected output for [01, 04] ?

Comment: my output should be for single number. that is why I want to convert to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return String.join(",", invertedMap.get(val));
```

In case `invertedMap.get(..)` returns an ArrayList with multiple values, they are separated by ",".